# Excel countifs overlapping criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

This is a follow-up to a prior question,  [Excel countif multiple criteria overlapping ranges and multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553584/excel-countif-multiple-criteria-overlapping-ranges-and-multiple-lines).

I now have to do this as a rear-view so instead of showing the number of people who were members in the target month but not three months later I need to show the number of people who have dropped out in the past three months.

At first I figured this would be as easy as just flipping the cell references around but that didn't address people who had dropped out in the prior two months. I then tried this formula but it didn't count correctly (and I'm still not sure why)

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5,"<>",C1:C5,"", D1:D5,"", E1:E5,"")
```

Then I used this formula but that double or triple counted people who dropped out.

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5,"<>",C1:C5,"")+COUNTIFS(B1:B5,"<>",D1:D5,"")+COUNTIFS(B1:B5,"<>",E1:E5,"")
```

Toy data:

```
    A       B        C       D       E
1   Mem#   May-16  June-16  July-16 Aug-16
2   001     197     197      197      
3   002             203      203    203
4   003     144     144
5   004     144     144
```

Desired output for August would be 3 (the number of people who were members in May but not in June, July, or August) but what I'm getting is 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5<>"")*((C2:C5<>"")+(D2:D5<>"")+(E2:E5<>"")<>3))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I used 1s for simplicity sake (will edit). I need to get a count, rather than a sum.